# Pair two drivers with one remote control IKEA TRÅDFRI

Tags: ikea-tradfri

I am going to buy two TRÅDFRI Drivers, one 10w and a another 30w. Is it possible to pair the drivers and use one remote control to dim them at the same without the gateway? Or does it work to pair the remote control with both drivers? It's impossible to wire them together because the distance between them is too far.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I've edited to improve the grammatical clarity, but please feel free to [edit] or roll-back if you feel that I have obfuscated your intent.

Answer (score 1):

By drivers I assume you mean [these](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/tradfri-driver-for-wireless-control-grey-50356187/).

Yes, you should be able to pair 2 of those to a single remote/switch without the need for a hub/gateway.